# Add a new item to top row of SlickGrid's dataView, like JavaScript's unshift

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I've just learned how to add new entries to SlickGrid's dataView; however, each entry is "pushed" into the grid as the last row.

How can I make new rows appear at the top of the grid?

Answer (score 3):

DataView.insertItem(insertBefore, item)

Comment: use 0 in place of insertBefore to get it at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The DataView uses a JS array for it's data. So if you generate a new array, or sort it to the order you want, SlickGrid should display it with that order.

```
data[0] = {id:id_0,...};
data[1] = {id:id_1,...};
.
.
.
dataView.setData(data);
```

Reorder your data array, update your dataView, invalidate and render the grid and it should work. Do keep in mind that the 'id' fields need to be unique for dataView to work.

Hope that helps!